# reinterpret_cast - double to char[] to double not working - C++

Tags: c++, qt, casting, udp, reinterpret-cast

I am trying to send some double's in a datagram via udpSendSocket.  The data is coming from a QT GUI and being sent to a VS2013 driver program (both in C++).  I am using a QDataStream to put data into a QByteArray which is then sent off.  Everything works fine for integers but I cannot make it work for doubles.

I have already confirmed that my transmission code works such that whatever is in datagram is being received by the driver program so I am doing all of my testing in the QT program.

At first I sent a double straight into QDataStream which claims to use IEEE 754 and then used *reinterpret_cast to convert it back to a double.

```
// QT Program
QByteArray datagram;
QDataStream out(&datagram, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_1);
out.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::SinglePrecision);

double test = 0.3;
out << test;
double recv = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(&datagram);
```

With that recv = 2.32e-317.

After that didn't work I focused on trying to convert a double to byte array back to double.  Multiple sources led me to believe this would work but it is not.

```
double test = 0.3;
unsigned char const* bytes = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(&test);
double recv = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(&bytes);
```

With that recv = 1.33e-317.

sizeof(double) returns 8.

What am I doing wrong with reinterpret_cast?  Should I be making this conversion a different way?  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you AndyG and Angew.  Both of your answers were very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to `reinterpret_cast` `&bytes`, but `bytes`. The former is the address of a pointer, the latter is the value (what's pointed to), which is where your `double` is.

Also, cast to `unsigned char*`, not `unsigned char* const`, so you don't cast away c-v qualifiers

```
double test = 0.3;
unsigned char* bytes = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&test);
double recv = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(bytes);
std::cout << recv << std::endl;
```

Output:

> 0.3

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/Sz6ICa)

Answer (score 2):

@AndyG is correct about the `bytes` part. As for `datagram`: `&datagram` gives you the address of the `QByteArray` object, not the address of its contents. For that, you need `data()`:

```
QByteArray datagram;
QDataStream out(&datagram, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_1);
out.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::SinglePrecision);

double test = 0.3;
out << test;
double recv = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(datagram.data());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `interpret_cast` example you're taking pointer to `bytes` which is already a pointer to the data bytes and casting to pointer to double. If you cast `bytes` instead and also cast to a `const double*` (because reinterpret_cast does not cast away constness) it will work:

```
double recv = *reinterpret_cast<const double*>(bytes);
```